# Is using generic type with x:DataType possible in MAUI?

Tags: c#, maui

I don't want to define `PetShopCat` actually if I can pass `PetShop<T>` to `x:DataType`.
Is it possible in MAUI?

```cs
public interface IAnimal
{
    string Name { get; }
}
public class Cat : IAnimal
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
}
public class PetShop<TAnimal> where TAnimal : IAnimal
{
    public TAnimal Animal { get; set; } = default(TAnimal)!;
}
public class PetShopCat : PetShop<Cat>;
```

```xml
<ContentPage 
             xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:Testing"            
             x:Class="Testing.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <loc:PetShop x:Key="petshop"  x:TypeArguments="loc:Cat" Animal="{loc:Cat Name=Cat}"/>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <Label x:DataType="loc:PetShopCat"
        BindingContext="{StaticResource petshop}"  
        Text="{Binding Animal.Name}"/>
</ContentPage>
```

#### Edit

Responding to the given comments.
The expected behavior is

```xml
<Label x:DataType="loc:PetShop" x:TypeArguments="loc:Cat"
      BindingContext="{StaticResource petshop}"  
      Text="{Binding Animal.Name}"/>
```

But it does not compile so I have to make `PetShopCat` and use

```xml
<Label x:DataType="loc:PetShopCat"
      BindingContext="{StaticResource petshop}"  
      Text="{Binding Animal.Name}"/>
```

Comment: AFAIK, no.  Using a generic would probably make it impossible to pre-compile the bindings, which is the main purpose of `DataType`.

Comment: it's a valid question that others might benefit from

Comment: @DG can you say a little about how this binding is supposed to behave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Yes, you can! Check this [PR](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/20625).

You won't find many examples, but you can look at [the test attached to the PR](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/20625/commits/d627b7dc84e7bcfcd25938c1276fec05e8216bfc).

I'm copying it to make it easier to read.

`Maui20616.xaml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.UnitTests"
             x:Class="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.UnitTests.Maui20616">
    <Label Text="{Binding Value}" x:DataType="local:ViewModel20616(x:String)" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Value}" x:DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel20616(x:String)}" />
</ContentPage>
```

`Maui20616ViewModel.cs`

```cs
public class ViewModel20616<T>
{
    public required T Value { get; init; }
}
```